# TLSharp Telegram API. Check phone registrered

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I've got a problem with TLSharp method `IsPhoneRegisteredAsync(...)`.

It always returns **true**, no matter the number I'm trying to check. Even for an input like "asdhbqaihbqwieuashdq23934327940scj0" it returns true.

Thanks for your help.

My code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connectClient(SETS.API_ID, SETS.API_HASH);
    }

    private async void connectClient(int api_id, string api_hash)
    {
        client = new TelegramClient(api_id, api_hash);

        api_ID_tb.Text = api_id.ToString();
        api_hash_tb.Text = api_hash;
        await client.ConnectAsync();

        if (client.IsConnected)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connect Succefull");

        }
    }

    async void CheckNumber(string number)
    { 

        bool q = await client.IsPhoneRegisteredAsync(number);

        MessageBox.Show(q.ToString());
    }

    private void numberCheckBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckNumber(number_tb.Text);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got same problem.
That`s how i solved it:

```
var req = new Auth.TLRequestSendCode
{
    PhoneNumber = myPhone,
    ApiId = ApiID,
    ApiHash = ApiHash
};
var resp = await client.SendRequestAsync<Auth.TLSentCode>(req);  
var phoneCodeHash = resp.PhoneCodeHash;
var isRegistered = resp.PhoneRegistered;
```

This is the same code as SendCodeRequestAsync (witch return only hash) but now we have access to Auth.TLSentCode.PhoneRegistered